# My server unmounted multiple drives and i don't know why?

Tags: debian, unmounting

so one of my servers was having issues this morning and when I went to investigate I found that the problem was that 4 of my drives seem to not be mounted anymore.

I am wondering if there may be a reason how this could have happened without someone going in and running umount 4 times. (I checked and I don't see any umount commands that have been run from my team)

I'm still a bit new to Linux but if there are logs I can look at please let me know.

Also, the server is running Debian 7.9

Comment: check with command `dmesg`

Answer (score 0):

Best location is `/var/log/dmesg`

You can find all logs that mention mounting or unmounting

```
$ sudo grep  mount /var/log/dmesg
```